# Java flatmap Iterator<Pair<Stream<A>, Stream<B>>> to Pair<Stream<A>, Stream<B>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to implement a method with the following signature:

```
public static <A,B> Pair<Stream<A>, Stream<B>> flatten(Iterator<Pair<Stream<A>, Stream<B>>> iterator);
```

Where the goal of the method is to flatten each of the stream types into a single stream and wrap the output in a pair. I only have an Iterator (not an Iterable) and I can't alter the method signature, so I have to perform the flattening in a single iteration.

My current best implementation is

```
public static <A,B> Pair<Stream<A>, Stream<B>> flatten(Iterator<Pair<Stream<A>, Stream<B>> iterator) {
    Stream<A> aStream = Stream.empty();
    Stream<B> bStream = Stream.empty();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        Pair<Stream<A>, Stream<B>> elm = iterator.next();
        aStream = Stream.concat(aStream, elm.first);
        bStream = Stream.concat(bStream, elm.second);
    }
    return Pair.of(aStream, bStream);
}
```

But while this is technically correct I'm not super happy with this for two reasons:

1. [Stream.concat warns against doing this kind of thing because it may lead to a StackOverflowError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-).
2. Stylistically I'd rather it be purely functional if possible instead of having to loop over the iterator and re-assign the streams throughout.

It feels like [Stream#flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) should be suited here (after transforming the input Iterator to a Stream using [Guava's Streams.stream(Iterator)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#stream-java.util.Iterator-), but it seems to not work because of the Pair type in the middle.

One additional requirement is that any of the iterator/streams may be very large (the input could contain anywhere from a single pair of exceedingly large streams to many of one item streams, for example) so solutions ideally shouldn't contain collecting results into in-memory collections.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well guava's `Streams.stream` is no magic and it's actually internally just:

```
StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, 0), false);
```

So probably no need to link that to your method while you could use it directly.

And you could use `Stream.Builder` just for that:

```
public static <A, B> Pair<Stream<A>, Stream<B>> flatten(Iterator<Pair<Stream<A>, Stream<B>>> iterator) {

    Stream.Builder<Stream<A>> builderA = Stream.builder();
    Stream.Builder<Stream<B>> builderB = Stream.builder();

    iterator.forEachRemaining(pair -> {
        builderA.add(pair.first);
        builderB.add(pair.second);
    });

    return Pair.of(builderA.build().flatMap(Function.identity()), builderB.build().flatMap(Function.identity()));
}
```

Comment: You could replace `StreamSupport.stream(…).forEach()` by just `iterator.forEachRemaining()`

Comment: @DidierL good point, thank you; this btw still collects to an ordered collection (almost like a `List` in your example), but it's the non-public `SpinnedBuffer`

Comment: “*Spined*” not “Spinned”. Because of the form, when the two-dimensional array is used internally, which is the reason why this is slightly more efficient than `ArrayList` for this use case, as it doesn’t need data copying on array capacity increase operations.

Comment: @Holger I only remotely *heard* at work this being more efficient then an `ArrayList`, not looked at the code, I can't really tell if I'll ever have the time for it. Thank you for at least some hints

Comment: Well, it’s rather simple. `ArrayList` has a one-dimensional array, so when its capacity is exhausted, a new, bigger array will be allocated and the contents copied. The `SpinedBuffer` has an array of arrays, which is not populated initially. When the current target array is full, it will be stored in the array of arrays and a new, also bigger array will be allocated as new target array, but no copying takes place. That design would complicate insertion or removals in the middle, but these aren’t supported anyway. But streaming over this two dimensional array of known size is still fast.

Answer (score 7):

Avoiding to collect the whole `Iterator` (like you actually do in the question) is quite difficult since you don't know how the resulting streams will be consumed: one could be entirely consumed, requiring to consume the iterator entirely as well, while the other is not consumed at all, requiring to keep track of all pairs produced – effectively collecting them somewhere.

Only if the streams are consumed more or less at the "speed", you could benefit from not collecting the whole iterator. But such consumption implies to either work with the iterator of one of the resulting streams, or to consume the streams in parallel threads – which would require additional synchronization.

I thus suggest to collect all pairs into a `List` instead, and then generate the new `Pair` from that list:

```
public static <A,B> Pair<Stream<A>, Stream<B>> flatten(Iterator<Pair<Stream<A>, Stream<B>>> iterator) {
    Iterable<Pair<Stream<A>, Stream<B>>> iterable = () -> iterator;
    final List<Pair<Stream<A>, Stream<B>>> allPairs =
        StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return Pair.of(
            allPairs.stream().flatMap(p -> p.first),
            allPairs.stream().flatMap(p -> p.second)
    );
}
```

This does not consume any of the original streams yet, while keeping a simple solution that avoids nested stream concatenations.

Answer (score 3):

First of all this would be a "more functional" version of your code, that you say you'd prefer stylistically:

```
<A, B> Pair<Stream<A>, Stream<B>> flattenFunctional(Iterator<Pair<Stream<A>, Stream<B>>> iterator) {
    return Streams.stream(iterator)
        .reduce(Pair.of(Stream.empty(), Stream.empty()),
            (a, b) -> Pair.of(
                Stream.concat(a.first, b.first),
                Stream.concat(a.second, b.second)));
}
```

The warning about a possible `StackOverflowError` still applies here as `Stream.concat` is used.

To avoid that and also thinking about performance and memory use for large datasets, I have the following suggestion (not functional at all). You can create a pair of custom `Iterator` (for `A`, `B` types) and use Guava's `Streams.stream()` to get a pair of streams. Put these custom iterators in a class with pair of stacks of iterators. If for instance in the first pair in `iterator`, `Stream<A>` has less elements than `Stream<B>` then after `Stream<A>` is exhausted, call `iterator.next()` and push an iterator of `B` into its stack. Here is the class with the pair of stacks (add a constructor):

```
class PairStreamIterator<A, B> {
    private final Iterator<Pair<Stream<A>, Stream<B>>> iterator;
    private final Queue<Iterator<A>> stackA = new ArrayDeque<>();
    private final Queue<Iterator<B>> stackB = new ArrayDeque<>();

    Iterator<A> getItA() {
        return new Iterator<A>() {
            @Override public boolean hasNext() {
                if (!stackA.isEmpty() && !stackA.peek().hasNext()) {
                    stackA.remove();
                    return hasNext();
                } else if (!stackA.isEmpty() && stackA.peek().hasNext()) {
                    return true;
                } else if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Pair<Stream<A>, Stream<B>> pair = iterator.next();
                    stackA.add(pair.first.iterator());
                    stackB.add(pair.second.iterator());
                    return hasNext();
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override public A next() {
                return stackA.peek().next();
            }
        };
    }    
    // repeat for Iterator<B>
}
```

and the `flatten` method:

```
<A, B> Pair<Stream<A>, Stream<B>> flattenIt(Iterator<Pair<Stream<A>, Stream<B>>> iterator) {
    final PairStreamIterator<A, B> pair = new PairStreamIterator<>(iterator);
    return Pair.of(Streams.stream(pair.getItA()), Streams.stream(pair.getItB()));
}
```

The 2 stacks will typically hold 1 or 2 iterators if you consume the 2 streams in the result pair of `flatten` at the same rate. Worst case scenario is if you plan to consume one of the streams of the resulting pair completely and then the other. In that case all the iterators required for the second flattened stream will remain in the stack of iterators. I don't think there is any way around that I am afraid. As these are stored in the heap in memory you won't get `StackOverflowError` albeit you may still get `OutOfMemoryError`

A possible caveat is the use of recursion in `hasNext`. That will only be a problem if you encounter many consecutive empty streams in your input.

Comment: I think it would be better using `Queue<Stream<A/B>>`  instead, to avoid taking the iterator of each incoming `Stream`. You would then have `Iterator<Stream<A/B>> getItA/B()` but that would not be a problem as you would just `fratMap(identity())` the streams you create from those iterators. Their implementation would probably be much simpler as well since you wouldn't need to have `remove()` and recursion in `hasNext()`: it would simply be `!stackA/B.isEmpty() || iterator.hasNext()`. The whole thing would still need synchronization though.